# iphone:Display JSON data in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, uitableview

I used the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 

    }    
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(120.0f, 5.0f, 70.0f, 55.0f);
            UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
            [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:myImage];
        }
        else  {

            int arrayIndex = [indexPath row]-1 ;
            mdict = [mmenuitems objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
            [mdict retain];
            cell.textLabel.text =[mdict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

I got correct JSON parsed message in mmenuitems,and used indexPath.row = 0 to display a logo.
But the problem is I didn't get the last item in tableview.
Also when I scrolls the tableview the data reloads randomly and same gets repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can gusse that you need to add 1 to your number of rows method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return [mmenuitems count]+1//add 1 for the logo cell
 }
```

So your rows count will be all the objects in the `mmenuitems` array + 1 cell for the logo.

**But**

a better way will be to add your logo to the table view `header view` and not to the table view rows, you can do it in your view did load after the table view is loaded:

```
        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(120.0f, 5.0f, 70.0f, 55.0f);
        UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
        [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:myImage];
```

It will add your logo to a view on top of the first table row and won't mix in your table rows. I believe it will resolve your repetition problem.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer.When I do as you said logo place above tableview,but can't scroll up.Is it possible to scroll it up with the tableview.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean that you can not scroll?

Comment: My headerview gets anchored at navigation bar.I want it too scroll up with tableview

Answer (score 1):

You could add + 1 to your numberOfRowsInSection method.

Comment: Thanks it helped to display the whole data.But still the problem of random reloading remains.

Comment: Can you post an NSLog of your mmenuitems?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using different identifiers for cells. Because the cell is being reused your contents are over written. It is not the good approach but it solves the problem nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to reset your cell everytime to avoid stale data

```
if (cell == nil) {
  //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 

}  
cell.textLabel.text = nil; //This clears any stale label
for(UIImageView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperView]; // This clears any subview added
}
```

Secondly,

Your number of rows should be

```
 [mmenuitems count] + 1
```

I believe currently it is just [mmenuitems count]